# Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library for an Android .AAR file which depends on the DataBinding

Tags: android, xamarin, aar

I have an aar file that depends on the data-binding library. So my question is how to make java bindings library for this aar file for xamarin android.
Noe: Used AndroidX as the dependency library in the aar file.

I tried to create the DLL files for the androidx.databinding library.

Comment: Check this: https://mallibone.com/post/xamarinandroid-and-mvvm-light-bindings

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman link provided relates to integration of  DataBinding in Xamarin.Android. According to definition of question .AAR file is already integrated with DataBinding which is now needed to create Java Binding Library.